# input type range continues drag

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a `range` element that looks like:

```
<div id='multi-range' data-lbound='0' data-ubound='50'>
  <input id="range_drag" type='range' min='-180' max='180' step='1' value='0' oninput='this.parentNode.dataset.lbound=this.value;'/>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is instead of you just dragging it, you can drag and throw the marker and it'll slide across the slider.

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oWORIdU/1) of attempting to achieve it. So I can get it moving on it's own, but having the ability to drag and throw the marker I can't figure out how I'd achieve it.

I tried using a `setInterval(function() {..}, 30);` and doing the `stepUp()` method. But I can't get it to fluidily slide like I'm trying.

Can anyone offer any advice/help on how I might achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might need the help of  a library like, [popmotion.io](https://popmotion.io/) (Not an affiliate) Because I think in this case you would want to track the pointer speed, and a way to calculate a decelerating motion tween. The "tween" would be the actual number for the set interval. But you might have to invert the tween because you would want the setInterval to increase. This is all off the top of my head, please forgive me if it's not 100%